# Regex - Remove lines between patterns keeping only first ocurrence

Tags: regex, lines

I need a REGEX that remove lines between 2 lines of a given pattern keeping only first occurrence of next lines. Something like uniq

Input:

```
Pattern.SomeText
RepeatedLine
RepeatedLine
RepeatedLine
Line

Pattern.OtherText
RepeatedLine

Pattern.ThirdText
RepeatedLine
TTTTRepeatedLine
```

Output:

```
Pattern.SomeText
RepeatedLine
Line

Pattern.OtherText 
RepeatedLine

Pattern.Third
TextRepeatedLine
TTTT
```

Lines with pattern always start with it, and the full line is unique. I want to make it with Notepad++.

Comment: Regex doesn't remove text.   You can use regex with a search and replace tool/scripting language like awk, bash or sed.  Better googling skills would also yield faster results.

Comment: You want to remove a repeated line between any two lines, or if those 2 lines are the same as the one they wrap? In your example, you remove the wrapping line instead of `TTTT` at the end. Does the line in between have to repeat, or just the ones that wrap?

Comment: I'm a little forced to use regex. Maybe some regex can match the repeated lines and I can replace it with emtpy char.

Comment: I need to be able to find lines with are repeated between 2 lines that match a pattern.

So I can flag the lines with the pattern, and then, the regex match the lines between that 2 ocurrences of the pattern that are repeated. Then I replace them by emtpy so they just go away

Comment: So which pattern should the 2 surrounding lines match? That they are identical? Does the line in between not have to match the 2 lines around it? If not, does it still have to repeat - as in it's present somewhere else in any position in the file?

Comment: Will that be enought `(?<!.)(.+\n)\1`.

Comment: Every line that delimites the text zone to fine repeated lines start with:

CINF\_E.*

Then we got some lines which can be repeated. That repeated lines, are the target.

Then we will find other CINF\_E.* which notices us that we reach the end of the text to find repeated lines. 

And it start again from that point. 

I usually do it manually but now I need to parse a 50k line text file so...

Comment: I though you were looking for an [uniq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniq) experience, but you add Something about repeated line that start with.. [Edit] this detail in your question.

Comment: Thats true. Thanks Drag, I'm editing it.

Comment: The only hard point is the fact that line in patern are not ordered. Well it will be 3 line in c#. 1/. Split on pattern 2/.for each patern block split on new line, clear duplicate 3/. join all with new line. Add 3 line to read file and check error. You should consider it.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/CWHM1b/1 simple regex will have to become so mutch more comple to handle this simple algo.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/duplicatelines.html

Comment: That's correct, If I sort them first using other software I might be able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a exemple of a regex that will be able to find consecutive duplicate line:

```js
const regex = /\n(.+)\n\1\n/g;
const str = `Pattern.SomeText
RepeatedLine
RepeatedLine
RepeatedLine
Line

Pattern.OtherText
RepeatedLine

Pattern.ThirdText
RepeatedLine
TTTT
RepeatedLine`;
const subst = `\n`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result:\n', result);
```

It will fail on not consecutive duplicate line.

And an exemple of a simple c# doing the exact requirement:

```c#
string pattern = "Pattern.";
string result = "";
string input = @"Pattern.SomeText
RepeatedLine
RepeatedLine
RepeatedLine
Line

Pattern.OtherText
RepeatedLine

Pattern.ThirdText
RepeatedLine
TTTT
RepeatedLine";

var a = input.Split(new string[] { pattern }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (var block in a)
{
    HashSet<string> lastLines = new HashSet<string>(
        block.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
    if (lastLines.Any())
    {
        result += pattern + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lastLines)+Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```